# Change of Eida’s accent of Hebrew

Tags: tefilla, minhag, mesorah-tradition, state-of-israel

Let’s say a certain Eida has a mesorah on how  to enunciate Hebrew, and now their children learn Israeli Hebrew and within one generation it completely replaces the traditional way they used for more than a millennia.

According to Halacha, because it is assur to change one’s mesorah of havora, must they switch back to their ancestral Hebrew when they are davening or saying Kriyat hatorah? Or are they allowed to continue using the Israeli pronunciation because they are now universally using it

Comment: For an example, my origin is Buhari and kavkazi, both have nearly identical mesorah for  niqqudim and pronounciation, which is very different from Edut hamizrah, for an example they both have kamas as an O  and pronounce Holam as Ü. 


Nowadays all young ppl of both eidot pronounce Hebrew the same way Israelis do but with Russian accent (no het, ayin, and Qof, Sade are pronounced like regular K and Tz)

Comment: Where does it say that is is ossur to change one's havora?

Comment: More than a millennia? Almost no one has such a tradition

Comment: "assur to change one’s mesorah of havora" what's your source?

Comment: [related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98361/if-a-mesorah-for-letter-pronunciation-is-rediscovered-would-we-have-to-change-o)