# What does שכם mean

Tags: names, vayishlach

Where does the name שכם come from? What exactly does it mean? I believe that names in the tanach are symbolic of qualities of whoever is that name, so what does שכם mean in relation to the person? Being “Ben chamor” is obviously a diss as him acting out like an animal, but what’s the first part of his name mean?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98372/759

Comment: Remember that big shouldered ogre from the old Popeye cartoons? Shekhem==shoulder

Answer (score 3):

Possible connections

1. שכם == early. Shekhem rushed (seduced) her.
2. Fortunate is he that slays Satan by doing Kriat Shema of the prayer, performing "If he's coming to kill you שכם /pre-empt and kill him" and "Abraham was שכם early up in the morning."

> והאי איהו דאוקמוהו מארי מתניתין, כל הקורא קריאת שמע, כאלו אוחז חרב פיפיות בידו, והא אוקמוהו על מטתו, להגן מן המזיקין, אבל בקריאת שמע דצלותא, אדון המזיקין קשור, לית ליה רשו למברח, וזכאה איהו מאן דשחיט ליה בההוא זמנא, לקיים (בא להורגך) **השכם** להרגו בצלותא, דאתמר בה **וישכם** אברהם בבקר, כל שכן מאן דלא חשש ליקריה לשחטא יצריה ושנאיה, דלית שנאיה לחוד אלא שנאיה דקודשא בריך הוא, דבכל יומא תבע חובין דבנוי לשחטא לון:
> T. Zohar 8b

Hence "The guy we (Shimon and Levi) got up early and slayed."

3. Another, Shekhem==shoulder. Hence big shouldered ogre.
4. Another, Shekhem is the Canaanite from the side of Ham the cursed perv.

הא אלין נפקין, הא אחרנין דפקין לפתחא, ואינון מארי דרועין, ואמרין אדנ"י שפתי תפתח, מיד עאלין נטורי תרעין, ואמרין רבון עלמא הא מארי דדרועין קא דפקין לפתחא, קלא נפיק ויימא, הא אינון מארי דדרועין בקשורא דתפלין, ובעטיפו דמצוה, דאתמר בהון **וישימו על שכם** שניהם, כגוונא דשם ויפת, דאתמר בהון ויקח שם ויפת את השמלה וגומר, וערות אביהם לא ראו, ערוה, איהי **מסטרא דחם**, ודא איהו יצר הרע, דמחמם גופיה לדבר ערוה (נ"א עבירה), וגלי עריין בעלמא, דאיהו מסטרא דנחש הקדמוני, דאתמר ביה ארור אתה מכל הבהמה, ובגין דהאי איהו מסטרוי, אמר **ארור כנען** וגומר: Ibid. 37a

Comment: Didn’t even think of those connections, thanks! Any idea how these could reflect on Shchem’s personality in the Parsha?

Comment: https://blogs.timesofisrael.com/a-burden-on-shoulders/