How to pronounce שׁוֹמְרִים?
Shalom to all.
I am not sure how to pronounce the following word, which comes up in prayer (e.g. in Tehillim 130):  שׁוֹמְרִים.
On one hand, I learned that Sheva after big vowels (Patach, Ṣere…) is independent. Based on this the pronunciation would be “shoMErim”.
On another hand, I’ve heard some people read this word as “shoMrim,” with a silent Sheva.
Which is correct? Please explain. Are there exceptions to the rule? Thank you.

A common grammatical mistake in that verse is to put the major pause on  לַ֝בֹּ֗קֶר
instead of on לַאדֹנָ֑י

Tangential, but patach is not generally classified as a long vowel.

The rules for sheva are here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shva

Joel can u explain pl

Two minor points: First, the correct term for what you call a “big vowel” is “long vowel”. Second, as @JoelK points out, Patach is a short vowel, not a long vowel. Kamatz Gadol, on the other hand, is a long vowel. I suggest editing your question to incorporate the above.

It’s a Shva na`.
Many people, especially in certain Ashkenazic communities, ignore the rules of Shva. Shva isn’t such an important vowel, so this (usually) isn’t problematic, but it’s not accurate either.
(Note: There is a scholarly opinion that this kind of Shva was silent in the Tiberian Masoretic tradition. Even if that was case, we don’t follow that rule today, so it’s irrelevant; and if it were relevant, we'd have to be extra careful with vowel length distinctions).

Who said "we don’t follow that rule today"?

@DoubleAA Every Tikkun/Chumash I’ve opened that’s either marked vocalic Shva or provided a list of rules for when Shva is vocalic.

As you noted, many people get these things wrong.

@DoubleAA I meant the normal people who aren’t taught this stuff, not Hebrew linguists and scholars who learn it. (At least, not any I’m aware of).

I don't understand your comment. Wouldn't you agree that among people who have studied the matter, some would say it's na and some would say it's nach, and most people haven't a clue and just make it up or follow what they found in some text?

@DoubleAA The only opinion I’ve read in sources written by such people regard a Shva after a (phonemic) long vowel as na`. The only source I’ve read regarding such a Shva as naħ, is in the educated speculation in the link I brought. I’ve only heard it read that way by non-established בעלי קריאה who don’t differentiate between long and short vowels.

You should discuss the whole story from a different perspective, and you'd have less confusion: According to the 5 rules of Elia Levita – which we all follow nowadays – it is a vocal sheva. According to the (earlier) tradition of the masoretes it's ambiguous.

@Kazibácsi I don't know who your "we all" is, but some of those are certainly not universally accepted.

@magicker72 In the sense that I'm not aware of any groups who'd follow the sheva rules in religious practice as discussed in דקדוקי הטעמים.

@Kazibácsi I also don't know anyone who pronounces קדמה like "keyd'ma", and many who pronounce יברכך like "y'varekhkha" (eg. as the Chorev tikkun indicates).

@magicker27 some Siddurim vocalize וִיחֻנֶּךָּ as וְיְחֻנֶּךָּ or וִיחֻנֶּךָ. That doesn’t mean such pronunciations have legitimacy. And I, for one, do pronounce קֵדְמָה with a Tzereh, because pronouncing it with a Segol is simply wrong. Common mistakes, even originating in print, are not legitimate, regardless of how many people are misled.

@Kazibácsi Those five rules are an oversimplification. Great for teaching kids the fundamentals; not so great for teaching בעלי קריאה.

@Qwertrl not sure you read the discussion clearly: I was talking about the sheva, not the tsere. Although, "wrong" is what you're calling the descendants of the Palestinian pronunciation, which has a long history!

@magicker72 I use a variant of the Palestinian vowel pronunciation, where length distinctions are preserved. קֵדְמָה begins with a long /e/ as represented by Tzereh, as opposed to a short /e/ as represented by Segol. Thus, I pronounce the word /ke-d-ma/ ([ˈqeːd̪mɐː]).

Any explanation for the downvote?

@Qwertrl I would rather refrain of making such comments, as acclaimed books like the Simanim Tikkun teach the 5 rules, as I also do when I teach בעלי קריאה.

@Kazibácsi That’s no reason to downvote the answer, which is unrelated to the comment.

@Kazibácsi [re your second comment] One word: תימנים.

I don't entirely get your comment. Yemenite pronunciation is more related to Babylonian. While I have a huge respect for them, one cannot randomly pick a pronunciation, but should follow his/her ancestors. I stick to Askenazi, which is clearly "wrong," but religion and science are two distinct categories. So I'd suggest to calm down your ego and don't make gross statements like that. (I have a strict no downvote policy, so find someone else to blame for the downvote.)

@Kazibácsi It took me a while to get what you meant. I personally am not a Yemenite, and don’t use their pronunciation, so my “ego” is irrelevant. However, I do know that although the Yemenite pronunciation is indeed based primarily on the Babylonian tradition, their pronunciation of Shva specifically is based on the Tiberian pronunciation. In fact, a couple of weeks ago, I found a recording of a Yemenite Jew singing לך אלי תשוקתי, clearly illustrating this point: https://www.nli.org.il/he/piyut/Piyut1song_010029900000005171/NLI

@Kazibácsi [cont’d] and regarding your statement that “one cannot… pick a pronunciation], see this answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98372/32959

@Kazibácsi [cont’d] I wasn’t looking for someone to blame. Your comment followed my request for an explanation, and I misunderstood it as a response. I’m sorry for the mistake.

@magicker72 I’m sorry, I understand now. I was operating under the premise of the following post (see under “ramifications”): https://forum.unilang.org/viewtopic.php?p=1074982#p1074982. I incorrectly imposed that premise onto your comment.

It's a bit complicated because sometimes rules conflict, for example שַׁרְבִיט, there's one rule that shva followed by a בּ is silent and followed by a ב is vocal, but usually a shva that closed patach is silent so this case is complicated, or in a case like מַלְכֵי vs מַלְכִּי, or similarly in וַתְּכַבֵּד what is type of dagesh is the תּ? It cannot be תּ because the patach makes it a closed syllable and a closed syllable it has to be rapha, It cannot be ת because because it has to open the syllable to be a vocal shva, and the כ rapha demands a vocal shva before it.
In your case probably is vocal because it's after a long vowel. In a shva after the qamets in שָׁ֫מְרוּ there seems to be an argument if silent or pronounced, if this qamets is considered long

Welcome to MiYodeya Josh and thanks for this first answer. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Not sure what’s uncertain about ותכבד? If the tav had a sheva nach then wouldn’t you expect the kaf to take a dagesh?

From כ rapha you see that ת is not vocal shava but there's a dagesh in the ת showing that it is pronounced. You have to say the the תּ is not doubled, and even if it has a dagash from the ו (like all forms) it'll have to be rejected

The first two are good examples of exceptions, but I don’t see how they are relevant. The last example (ותכבד) is just completely false.

@QwertyCTRL. Hopefully I clarified what's wrong with ותכבד

Shva only affects the FOLLOWING letter; NOT the letter that takes it.

@QwertyCTRL. The ת being after a patach tells you that it's rapha , you cant have a rapha letter open a syllable, but the כ rapha tells you that it did open the syllable otherwise it would be כּ

The Tav being after a Patach does NOT tell you it's "rapha".  All it means is that the word starts with a closed syllable. The Tav takes a dagesh chazzaq. Thus, the word is pronounced "vat-te-chab-bed". As you can see, the Tav both closes the first syllable, and begins the next one (with the Shva). The Shva is thus pronounced. Because the Shva is pronounced, the following letter--Chaf--is Rafe.

@QwertyCTRL.  1 A בגדכפת that does not open a syllable is rapha, just "read". 2 there is no evidence that a dagash חזק makes it not rapha, if you want to double the ת according to you the first would have to be rapha and the second not

@QwertyCTRL. That a בגדכפת letter is rapha before a vowel is litterally in the basic Wikipedia article

@Josh Wouldn’t you have the same issue with the ת in ותעל? That is should be rapha in order to close the first syllable of the word?

@JoelK my main point was that a lot of these rules are sometimes circular. In these cases like ותכבד the dagesh is likely קל and not חזק, you sometimes don't have the dagesh probably for this reason in הַמְבַקֵּש or וַיְדַבֵּר or מִלְמַעְלָה where the shva needs to be vocal, but this doesn't always happen. The ט and all the בגדכפת seem to be the most stubborn and always keep the dagesh, this likely means that the dagesh in these cases are קל or something less then חזק, like In שִחֵת where there's some gemination but not full

@Josh How can the dagesh in the tav in ותכבד be kal? What is closing the previous syllable?

@JoelK in this case it remains open like in the other examples I gave l. The examples are evidence that the dagesh is likely קל, tho I don't think it's accepted by everyone

Hold on. וַתְּכַבֵּד. Pronounced “Vat-te-Chab-bed. What here confuses you? What precisely do you find impossible or exceptional? Let’s work through this one step at a time.

@Josh when do you ever have dagesh kal after an open syllable? I’m not aware of anyone who thinks that is possible

@JoelK isn't there discussion about בתים?  Also ויחד יתרו is weird

@Heshy ויחד ought to have a sheva nach on the chet, which would cause a dagesh kal in the dalet. The shva morphs into a patach becuase it's a guttural, but the dagesh kal remains. See Ibn Ezra. בתים - yes, there is debate if the dagesh in the tav is kal or chazak. If it's kal then we have an exception that proves the rule.
