# Deuteronomy 31:19 Torah Leining

Tags: torah-reading, deuteronomy, haazinu, chinuch-education

I  see some discussion on [Trope](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/993/trop-cantillation-for-leining) and the [cantillation symbols](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22586/were-our-symbols-for-trope-and-nekudos-created-by-the-masoretes-or-transmitted), but little has been addressed by way of **why** you lein.  I read [Deuteronomy 31:29](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0531.htm) in Scripture today and it made me wonder, **Is it possible that in your heritage Torah has always been sung and that this verse is why Torah leining is taught to your children?**

I had always thought the song here referred to only a portion in Deuteronomy. But [I saw Deuteronomy 31:29 cited as the reason you copy your own torah scrolls](http://www.jewfaq.org/613.htm), and it connected Torah leining with this verse in my mind.  I imagine, that if Moses turned any portion of it into song you would remember it throughout your generations, song just does that!

Deuteronomy 31:19

> וְעַתָּה, כִּתְבוּ לָכֶם אֶת-הַשִּׁירָה הַזֹּאת, וְלַמְּדָהּ אֶת-בְּנֵי-יִשְׂרָאֵל, שִׂימָהּ בְּפִיהֶם:  לְמַעַן תִּהְיֶה-לִּי הַשִּׁירָה הַזֹּאת, לְעֵד--בִּבְנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל. ‏

Deuteronomy 31:22

> וַיִּכְתֹּב מֹשֶׁה אֶת-הַשִּׁירָה הַזֹּאת, בַּיּוֹם הַהוּא; וַיְלַמְּדָהּ, אֶת-בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל. ‏

I was wondering if this was WHY you lein and why leining Torah is part of preparing your children for bar mitzvah and bat mitzvah--helping them become sons of commandment and and daughters of commandment.

[Related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71483/why-do-jews-copy-their-own-torah-scrolls).

Comment: The song in that verse is the "Haazinu" song found a couple verses later in Chapter 32. Note especially the last verse in Chapter 31.

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I had always thought.  How far does the song extend though?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song_of_Moses It's 32:1-43.

Comment: I think I wondered because this Jewish site cites that verse for the reason you copy your own torah Scrolls:  http://www.jewfaq.org/613.htm  Should I add that into the question or delete the question?

Comment: If you'd like to ask what the referent of that verse is (a reasonable question given the evidence you have) you should ask that separately. Better not to clog this question with too many issues.

Comment: So ask a separate question about the Jewfaq.org reference to this verse you mean?  and leave this question as is.  Maybe link the two questions?

Comment: A few items - The term "shira" is usually translated as "song". However, it does not necessarily mean using musical notes. What makes something a "shira", generally, is the use of language and form. Usually, there is a "balance form", i.e. verbds used at the beginning of the verse may be used at its end in reverse format. That's one of many forms. 2 - The origin of using cantillation is Masoretic, but it was primarily for grammar. I'm not sure when the requirement of music came in, and that's definitely something I should research. At any rate, this verse is not the source of it AFAIK.

Comment: @Sarah Sounds like a pretty good plan to me. Always good to clarify your various assumptions individually. That way you can construct informed and useful larger questions.

Comment: Sarah - I'm having a tough time understanding the focus in this question. Do you want to know if, specifically, this verse is the source for chanting the Torah with musical notes? Or, do you want to know, in general, why the Torah needs to be sung at all? Or, do you want to know what is the purpose of cantillation notes as a whole? Please edit your question, appropriately, and delete irrelevant items.

Comment: I edited out the stray thoughts and musings.  I hope that helps.  Thanks.

Comment: @Sarah Ancient books and stories were always passed down via song. Adding a melody to something always helps people remember it. The same is true from native american cultures, to bedouin cultures, to islam, and to Judaism and ancient Christianity. However, at some point Torah "leining" drifted away from music for the point of memorization, to music for the sake of performance as everyone was able to read books, and books became plentiful

Comment: Its funny how coming from one culture into another, things that a people take for granted as just normal, seem so beautiful and such a discovery to another.  Coming from a Christian background, sure there were verses we sang, but never all of Scripture.  Here, in Judaism, Scripture was so revered that someone took the time to compose and notate and preserve the tropes, their significance to the understanding of the text and pass it faithfully onto their children.  Their whole identity, life and culture is infused, wrapped up in and build around Torah and the God behind it.  This is impressive.

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though Rambam does not cite specific Scriptural references, but in Sanhedrine 29b, the Mitzva for each person to copy Torah for themselves is connected to Deuteronomy 31:19 http://www.yctorah.org/component/option,com_docman/task,doc_download/gid,653/

Your tradition draws upon this verse as the source of the mitzva for each person to copy Torah.  Thus it extends the reach of the verse beyond the song of Moses in their understanding or application.
[See related Q & A](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71483/from-which-passage-is-the-jewish-mitzva-to-write-a-torah-scroll-for-themselves)

While it might seem logical that the passage may also have extended in their understanding or application as the origin of Torah leining, this is not what Jewish tradition maintains.

In regards to chanting torah it seems an entirely different passage comes to bear. [My Jewish Learning](http://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/cantillation-chanting-the-bible/) attributes the practice of chanting Torah to Ezra and cites [Sanhedrin 99a](http://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.99a?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all).

Comment: the first link is not good can you fix it

Comment: Sorry kouty.  I cannot find it.   Thank you for pointing this professor ut though.  Amd thank you for your edit to the question.

Comment: I've definitely heard that the cantillation comes from tradition passed down from Moshe though. The Gemara on Nedarim 37: is possibly discussing that. And Machzor Vitri Siman 429. However, not based on the verse you mentioned.

Comment: See also https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90#cite_note-3