# Is the mitzva to write a Torah scroll for oneself derived from Deuteronomy 31:19?

Tags: sources-mekorot, mitzvah, sefer-torah, vayelech

[This site](http://www.jewfaq.org/613.htm) cites (under Torah - 16) [Deuteronomy 31:19](http://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.31.19?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) for the reason that there is a mitzva to write your own Torah scroll.

> That every person shall write a scroll of the Torah for himself.

Is that an accurate reference?

In a comment on a related question  [Deuteronomy 31:19 Torah Leining](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/71457/deuteronomy-3119-torah-leining?noredirect=1#comment208668_71457)
I saw that the verse was only about the Song of Moses. So I wondered if Deuteronomy 31:19 was the right source for this mitzva.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is how the [Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides), Maimonides, codifies it (and he is [one of the greatest codifiers of Jewish law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishneh_Torah)).

It is the last of the 613 mitzvot (commandments). As R Jack Abramowitz [describes it](https://www.ou.org/torah/mitzvot/taryag/mitzvah613/)

> The last of the 613 mitzvos is the obligation for every man to write a
>   sefer Torah. Recognizing that not every individual possesses the
>   requisite skill to do so himself, one may employ another person to do
>   so on his behalf. Nowadays, it’s very common for people to sponsor
>   letters, words or verses when their shul commissions a Torah scroll to
>   be written. In this way, people can participate in the performance of
>   this mitzvah.
>
> The reason for this mitzvah is to help spread Torah. If everybody
>   fulfilled this mitzvah, everyone would have a Torah – think how
>   well-versed people could be! Our verse says, “Write for yourselves
>   this song” – that is, the Torah – “and teach it to the children of
>   Israel.” It’s not enough merely to write a Torah and leave it in a
>   closet; it was meant to be taught!
>
> A person is obligated in this mitzvah even if he inherited a sefer
>   Torah from his father. While the mitzvah is specifically to write a
>   Torah scroll, every person should strive to acquire and to study other
>   books of Torah knowledge.
>
> This mitzvah applies to men in all times and places. It is discussed
>   in the Talmud in the tractates of Sanhedrin (21b), Baba Basra
>   (13b-14b) and Menachos (30a-b). It is codified in the Shulchan Aruch
>   in Yoreh Deah 274. This mitzvah is #18 of the 248 positive mitzvos in
>   the Rambam’s Sefer HaMitzvos and #15 of the 77 positive mitzvos that
>   can be observed today as listed in the Chofetz Chaim’s Sefer HaMitzvos
>   HaKatzar.

Answer (score 0):

The question is highly perceptive. As [this reference shows](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/979201/jewish/Writing-a-Personal-Torah-Scroll.htm) the matter is a source of discussion which Maimonides explains.

> The 613th mitzvah of the Torah is the obligation for every Jew to
>   write a Torah scroll. In the words of the verse: "And now, write for
>   yourselves this song, and teach it to the Children of Israel. Place it
>   into their mouths, in order that this song will be for Me as a witness
>   for the children of Israel."
>
> **Although Rashi and some other commentaries understand this as a
>   command only to write the Torah portion that immediately follows,
>   Ha'azinu (which is referred to as a song), the Talmud understands it
>   as an obligation to write the entire Torah.**
>
> Maimonides explains that although the word "song" in the verse is
>   referring to Ha'azinu, since it is forbidden to write only a single
>   portion of the Torah on a scroll, it is understood that there is an
>   obligation to write the entire Torah.

Comment: Thank you Avrohom for your edit and for your answer.  I find both concise and you provide answer to why Rambam said what he said.  May I ask where it is forbidden to write only a single portion of the Torah on a scroll?